# access denied for user "@'localhost' (using password: no)

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I AM TRYING TO MAKE CONNECTION TO MY DB ITS GIVE ME ACCESS DENIED PLEASE HELP ME

```
String query= "SELECT * FROM id ";
     try{

       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
       Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xiiip,root,student");
      Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
      while (rs.next())
       {
           int a=rs.getInt("rollno");
           String b=rs.getString("name");
            int c=rs.getInt("Maths");
            int d=rs.getInt("eng");
            int e=rs.getInt("ip");
            model.addRow(new Object[] {a,b,c});        
      }

       }
       catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xiiip,root,student");
```

To

```
Connection con=(Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xiiip'', root,student);
```

Because root is the username and student is the password.. 
The name of the database is xiiip..
Refer to api docs.. 
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html